# Can classic asp / vbscript be used to generate or a file descriptor for a locally stored image?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Im working on a project where I need to make an api call and one aspect requires I send the API a 'file descriptor' for an image stored locally on the users machine so the api can perform an 'upload' routine for that specified image...

Im posting data to and receiving data from the API fine, thats working beautifully... one particular piece of data needs to be a 'file descriptor' that represents an image file that exists on our windows server where the website is stored.

I DO have the local path to the image, but have no idea how to create / get the file descriptor.

My research hasnt turned up much in the way of vbscript / asp so Im not sure its possible.

Is anyone familiar with how to do this with .ASP (not .net though)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

API means application programming interface. Which API are you talking about. The Windows API can't be called by vbscript. So that is that.

Now FileDescriptors are part of the shell and most of the shell is idispatch com based and accessible to vbscript. So what are you trying to do.

Comment: the api is just a 3rd party solution my client is interested in using and one particular facet of the back and forth communication my code with have with their api is for me to post to a url a string of variables, one of which needs to be a 'file descriptor' that represents an image on my server.  so the api isnt really a factor in what Im trying to figure out -- I have all the api related data exchanges working fine, just the issue of taking an image I know exists on my server and getting the 'file descriptor' for that image is what Im after. - hope Im explaining this clearly.  thanks.

Comment: Not really. In Windows a FileDescriptor is a data structure describing a file being dragged, it contains it's last modified date etc. In Unix it has a different meaning dealing with disk structure. What do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for your help - sounding like its a whole different arena (file system, etc.) so I'll just improvise.  Thanks for taking the time with me on this though, I appreciate it, I know it wasnt a lot to go on to begin with.  Best.

Comment: To be honest if your 3rd party API is asking for a file descriptor I think it just means it is asking for your filename or file meta data in some bespoke format defined by the API documentation. But without knowing which API your using it is hard to say. Web services are a very common form of API now @tamak you may have the wrong end of the stick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first if it will work for you

```
 dim fs,f
 set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 set f=fs.GetFile("c:\test.txt")
 Response.Write("The File names without extension of the file are: ")
 Response.Write(f.ShortName)
 set f=nothing
 set fs=nothing
```

Running it in a loop properly should give you all the info about your images in the folder if you concatinate it or if you can send image file name as description it will be there as well...
Here is some info what you can get: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_file.asp